# Dell N-Series SNMP, resolve mac adress from interface list

Tags: snmp, dell

I can easily pull the interface list status, by doing a OID walk. 
This is how I can tell whether a port is online or offline.

[image]

To physically resolve the location I then walk. (1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2)
[image]

Now I would like to determine, what the mac address on each connected port is. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text, then paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866703/snmp-get-complete-mac-table-in-one-call

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Zac67 I have tried to walk the 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3 OID, but it seems to be not supported by Dell servers

Comment: What I can retrieve from the server is the ip Adress to mac Adress table. Is there a Mapping from Mac/Ip adress to interface?

Comment: @merl Then you'll need to pull the MIB files for the N-series from Dell and find out where they're hiding the table. The ARP table and the MAC/port table are different things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get the exact MIB here (https://www.dell.com/support/home/de/de/debsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=00mxr). The agend Bridge-Mib and the correct OID (1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2), can be found in it. Is it possible that the switch blocks the walk? I'm using SNMP V2c with a public community.

Comment: "_Now I would like to determine, what the mac address on each connected port is._" That really doesn't make sense because there can be many MAC addresses connected to a switch interface. What you want to do is look at the switch MAC address table that has every MAC address that the switch knows, and on which interface the MAC address was seen.

Answer (score 0):

Like a snmpwalk on `ifPhysAddr` MIB, and then cross reference the result with the other OIDs to extract only the connected ports?